# Image watermark in PHP slim framework

Tags: php, slim, watermark

I have a php script that watermarks image by putting the watermark in center of a product image. It works on php7 but switching code to SLIM Framework it is not processing.

working code snippet in php7:

```
 $tool = new App();
$file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
$target = $temp_folder.$now."_temp_".$file_name; 
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target);
$processed_file_path = "../UPLOADS/products/images/";
$tool->create_watermark($target, $processed_file_path);// works with php7
```

Here comes the script With SLIM3 framework

```
$target = $temp_folder.$now."_temp_".$file_name; 
$processed_file_path = $container->get('upload_directory');
// upload_directory is: $container['upload_directory'] = __DIR__ . '/UPLOADS';
WaterFunction::create_watermark($target, $processed_file_path);
```

Here is the php7 function that creates watermark:

```
   public function create_watermark($source_file_path, $output_file_path)
{
    list($source_width, $source_height, $source_type) = getimagesize($source_file_path);
    if ($source_type === NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($source_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_file_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_file_path);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    define('WATERMARK_OVERLAY_IMAGE', '../images/watermark.png');

    $overlay_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng(WATERMARK_OVERLAY_IMAGE);
    $overlay_width = imagesx($overlay_gd_image);
    $overlay_height = imagesy($overlay_gd_image);
    // we need a mathematical formular to place the logo in the middle!
    $posFromLeft = ($source_width-$overlay_width)/2;
    $posFromTop = ($source_height-$overlay_height)/2;// formular performed by Amy Abafor
    imagecopy(
        $source_gd_image,
        $overlay_gd_image,
        $posFromLeft,
        $posFromTop,
        //  $source_height - $overlay_height, // $dst_y
        0, //$src_x
        0, //$src_y
        $overlay_width, // $src_w
        $overlay_height//int $src_h
    );
    imagepng($source_gd_image, $output_file_path, 9);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($overlay_gd_image);
}
```

Here is the SLIM FRAMEWORK Class processing watermark

```
Class WaterFunction{
public function create_watermark($source_file_path, $output_file_path)
{

    global $container;

   $water_mark_path = $container->get('upload_directory');

   $water_mark_image = $water_mark_path . '/images/watermark.png';

    list($source_width, $source_height, $source_type) = getimagesize($source_file_path);
    if ($source_type === NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($source_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_file_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file_path);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_file_path);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    $overlay_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($water_mark_image);
    $overlay_width = imagesx($overlay_gd_image);
    $overlay_height = imagesy($overlay_gd_image);
    // we need a mathematical formular to place the logo in the middle!
    $posFromLeft = ($source_width-$overlay_width)/2;
    $posFromTop = ($source_height-$overlay_height)/2;// formular performed by Amy Abafor
    imagecopy(
        $source_gd_image,
        $overlay_gd_image,
        $posFromLeft,
        $posFromTop,
        //  $source_height - $overlay_height, // $dst_y
        0, //$src_x
        0, //$src_y
        $overlay_width, // $src_w
        $overlay_height//int $src_h
    );
    imagepng($source_gd_image, $output_file_path, WATERMARK_OUTPUT_QUALITY);
    imagedestroy($source_gd_image);
    imagedestroy($overlay_gd_image);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple and solved. in slim i used direct image watermark link.
thus:

```
http://...... /images/watermark.png
```